# python - appending different columns from a file to different lists?

Tags: python, file, list

I have a tab-delimited file as below:

```
A    3    A    6
B    6    B    9
C    0    C    2
```

I wish to read the file in as below:

```
LIST = [['A', '3'], ['B', '6'], ['C', '0'], ['A', '6'], ['B', '9'], ['C', '2']]
```

The order is not important. I am only concerned that each row is read in increments of two and assigned to a sub list.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
S :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straightforward way would be:

```
>>> n = []
>>> for line in open(fname):
    els = line.split('\t')
    n.append(els[:2])
    n.append(els[2:])


>>> n
[['A', '3'], ['A', '6'], ['B', '6'], ['B', '9'], ['C', '0'], ['C', '2']]
```

maybe slightly more efficient would be:

```
>>> g = (line.split('\t') for line in open(fname))
>>> [els[i:i+2] for els in g for i in range(0, 4, 2)]
[['A', '3'], ['A', '6'], ['B', '6'], ['B', '9'], ['C', '0'], ['C', '2']]
```

Comment: eeeewww :). there should be a better way to do this. At least say `(0,2)` instead of that `range(0,4,2)`. Also if you do just `split()` (no arguments), it will split on space, tab, new lines... you can just do `g = open(fname).read().split()`

Answer (score 0):

This question actually allows for some Pythonic solutions.

```
l = open(fname).read().split()
LIST = zip(l[::2], l[1::2])
```

That's all there is to it. "[Bam!](http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/Elzar)"

Or we can "[knock it up a notch](http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/Elzar)":

```
def couple(i):
    while True:
        yield (i.next(), i.next())

LIST = [w for w in couple(iter(open(fname).read().split()))]
```

Additional benefits of those are that they will read the file in pairs, no matter if there are 4 columns (as in the example) or 6, 2... whatever

---

See also 
[pythonic-way-to-split-comma-separated-numbers-into-pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870652) and 
[how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443)